# Python Mediapipe AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pose_landmarks'

Tags: python, mediapipe

im trying to use Mediapipe as a pose estimator with pose_landmarker task using the mediapipe documentation code with some alterations, however it keeps spitting out this error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pose_landmarks'

i have no idea how to fix it , thanks in advance :)

```
from mediapipe import solutions
from mediapipe.framework.formats import landmark_pb2
import numpy as np
import mediapipe as mp
from mediapipe.tasks import python
from mediapipe.tasks.python import vision
import cv2
import time


VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

def draw_landmarks_on_image(rgb_image, detection_result):
  pose_landmarks_list = detection_result.pose_landmarks
  annotated_image = np.copy(rgb_image)


  for idx in range(len(pose_landmarks_list)):
    pose_landmarks = pose_landmarks_list[idx]


    pose_landmarks_proto = landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmarkList()
    pose_landmarks_proto.landmark.extend([
      landmark_pb2.NormalizedLandmark(x=landmark.x, y=landmark.y, z=landmark.z) for landmark in   pose_landmarks
    ])
    solutions.drawing_utils.draw_landmarks(
      annotated_image,
      pose_landmarks_proto,
      solutions.pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS,
      solutions.drawing_styles.get_default_pose_landmarks_style())
  return annotated_image


base_options = python.BaseOptions(model_asset_path='pose_landmarker_full.task')
options = vision.PoseLandmarkerOptions(
    base_options=base_options,
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=vision.PoseLandmarkerResult,
    num_poses=3,
    output_segmentation_masks=False)
detector = vision.PoseLandmarker.create_from_options(options)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
while cap.isOpened():
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if not ret:
    break
  frame_np = np.array(frame)
  timestamp = int(round(time.time()*1000))

  mp_image=mp.Image(image_format=mp.ImageFormat.SRGB,data=frame_np)
  frame=mp_image.numpy_view()
  detection_result = detector.detect_async(mp_image,timestamp)
  annotated_image= draw_landmarks_on_image(frame,detection_result) 
  cv2.imshow("frame",annotated_image)
  if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break



cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Welcome ! Apparently `detector.detect_async(mp_image,timestamp)` is `None`

Answer (score 0):

It helps to take a look at the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/api/solutions/python/mp/tasks/vision/PoseLandmarker#detect_async):

```
detect_async(
    image: mp.Image,
    timestamp_ms: int,
    image_processing_options: Optional[_ImageProcessingOptions] = None ) -> None
```

Especially this note:

> The results will be available via the "result_callback" provided in
> the PoseLandmarkerOptions.

So the results of running detection are only available within that callback. The [guide](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/pose_landmarker/python#live-stream) shows an example of setting the options with a callback that prints the landmarks:

```
import mediapipe as mp

BaseOptions = mp.tasks.BaseOptions

PoseLandmarker = mp.tasks.vision.PoseLandmarker
PoseLandmarkerOptions = mp.tasks.vision.PoseLandmarkerOptions
PoseLandmarkerResult = mp.tasks.vision.PoseLandmarkerResult
VisionRunningMode = mp.tasks.vision.RunningMode

# Create a pose landmarker instance with the live stream mode:
def print_result(result: PoseLandmarkerResult, output_image: mp.Image, 

timestamp_ms: int):
    print('pose landmarker result: {}'.format(result))

options = PoseLandmarkerOptions(
    base_options=BaseOptions(model_asset_path=model_path),
    running_mode=VisionRunningMode.LIVE_STREAM,
    result_callback=print_result)

with PoseLandmarker.create_from_options(options) as landmarker:
  # The landmarker is initialized. Use it here.
  # ...
```

In your case, instead of `print_results`, you would add a function that draws the landmarks.